# Keyup only after last key with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm coding a simple script to extract database informations on input keyup event.

The problem i have is that the keyup event is always repeated everytime the user press a key. How can i make it working only after the last key pressed?

I think i should use a function like setTimeOut() after every keyup, But i don't know how... can you make me a simple example please?

Sorry for my bad english :)

Here is what i was trying to do:

```
$("input").keyup(function()
{
    var timer=setTimeout(function() {
    }, 1000);
    if(!timer)
    {
        //do .post ajax request
    }
});
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
var timer;

$("input").on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);  //clear any running timeout on key up
    timer = setTimeout(function() { //then give it a second to see if the user is finished
        //do .post ajax request //then do the ajax call
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You're basically there.  You just need to clear the timer if they enter another letter; otherwise, your callback will execute after the 1000 ms regardless of whether they keep typing.

Something like this should work:

```
$("input").keyup(function (event)
{
    var self = this;
    if (self.timer)
        clearTimeout(self.timer);

    self.timer = setTimeout(function ()
    {
        self.timer = null;
        alert(self.value);
    }, 1000);

});
```

Where I just have the alert, you'd put your ajax code to write back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you do this with onchange event you don't need to put time interval checks. whenever you complete your input and change the focus. it triggers onchange event for you

```
$("input").onchange(function()
{
   //extract database info
}
```