# jQuery Ajax calls issue with onKeyUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a search form where the field calls a function called autoSend() onKeyUp. This is great but as the database is getting larger I am seeing a situation where ajax requests are still pending when the next key is pressed which can result in bad search results.

I have implemented a solution I found on Stack but this falls short where if someone searched for 'Smith' then if on the keyup for 't' the request was still pending it only searches on 'smit' rather than 'smith'

Can anyone advise?

Thanks

```
var loading = false;

function autoSend() {
    if (loading == false) {
        loading = true;

        $.ajax({
            url:'../customer/search.cfm',
            type:'POST',
            data: $("#searchForm").serialize()
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            $("#reportdata").html(data)
            loading = false;
        })
        .done(function() {
            loading = false;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, `success()` deferred method is deprecated, set logic in `done()` callback (even if i guess in your code, your `done()` should be `always()`). Secondly, you probably want to debounce sending ajax request using a timer and abort any previously made ajax request. But aborting client side doesn't abort it server side

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520164/keyup-only-after-last-key-with-jquery might be useful

Comment: @user3154108 good dupe even the accepted answer has typo, `clearInterval(timer);` should be `clearTimeout(timer);` (edited now!)  and not handling the fact that any previously made request should be aborted

Comment: Thanks for your input, both have helped a lot. @user3154108 the method used in the link worked perfectly!